# Switch structure: entering a zip code to associate it with a geographic area but only returning the first digit?

Tags: java, char, switch-statement, zipcode

Before everything else, here's the code I came up with:

```
package decision;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class ZIP {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner (System.in);

    char zipCode;

        System.out.println("Enter your zip code number: ");
            zipCode=input.next().charAt(0);

            switch (zipCode) {
            case 0: case 2: case 3:
                System.out.println(zipCode + " is on the East Coast.");
                break;
            case 4: case 5: case 6: 
                System.out.println(zipCode + " is in the Central Plains Area.");
                break;
            case 7:
                System.out.println(zipCode + " is in the South.");
                break;
            case 8: case 9:
                System.out.println(zipCode + " is in the West.");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println(zipCode + " is an invalid ZIP Code.");
            }
    }

}
```

(Just learned about switch structures today and wondered where they were when my code was full of nested if's lol.)

Basically, this program is supposed to accept only the first digit of the zip code a user enters (which, he enters in full - five digits) but I want the console to print all five digits of the zip code during output.

For example, the user would put in `87878`. The program will only accept the first digit (which is 8) to associate it with a specific area, but when I print it out, I want the console to print: "(zipCode) is in the West."

I've tried changing the data type of zipCode to char, so that I can use the `charAt(0)` method I learned only very recently, but given the code I provided, the console would print this out:

```
Enter your zip code number: 
20098
2 is an invalid ZIP Code.
```

What can I do to get my desired output? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
This is how I want the console to look like:

```
Enter your zip code number: 
20098
20098 is on the East Coast.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that for example if `zipCode` is equals to `'0'`, its int value is actually equals to `48` and not `0`.

If you do :

```
char c = '0';
System.out.println((int)c);
```

You will see that it outputs `48`. Why ?

Because in Java, the char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character (see encoding table below).

[image]

If you take a look at this table, you see that 0 is encoded as `0x0030 = 3*16^1 = 48`, 1 as `0x0031 = 3*16^1 + 1*16^0 = 49`.

So to avoid that :

1. Change your case labels as `case 48: case 50: case 51` (`for 0,2,3`) and so on
2. Change your case labels as `case '0': case '2': case '3'` and so on.

Personally, I would recommend you the second solution which is actually more clear and simple. 
 
[**Demo here.**](http://ideone.com/vWY93x)

If you want to keep testing on integer values in your case labels, you could do :

```
int zipCode = Character.getNumericValue(input.next().charAt(0));
```

**Edit :**

To get the output you want you can store the input of the user in a `String` variable.

```
    System.out.println("Enter your zip code number: ");
    String code = input.next();
    char zipCode = code.charAt(0);

        switch (zipCode) {
        case '0': case '2': case '3':
            System.out.println(code + " is on the East Coast.");
            break;
        /**/
        default:
            System.out.println(code + " is an invalid ZIP Code.");
        }
```

Comment: Actually, the problem is not so that the type is char and not int, but that the int value of '0' is not 0, but 48: the Unicode value of the char '0'.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, made the clarifications.

Comment: @ZouZou Thanks! It makes sense. You were a big help!